# How to disable drag Compose pager after upgrade to v0.19.0?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

As title, Android Compose Pager layout removed **dragEnabled** after **v0.19.0**. Is there any other way to disable drag pager ?

Guide: https://google.github.io/accompanist/pager/

Comment: I'm using the current version of Accompanist and using the pager but have no idea what "dragging" is. And since it was removed, I have no idea what it did. Please explain.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since Accompanist [**0.24.1-alpha**](https://github.com/google/accompanist/releases/tag/v0.24.1-alpha), which requires Compose version **1.2.0-alpha02** or newer, `userScrollEnabled` argument was added:

```
HorizontalPager(
    userScrollEnabled = false
) {
}
```

It requires Compose **1.2.0-alpha01** because in this version same functionality [was added](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-foundation#1.2.0-alpha01) to `LazyColumn`/`LazyRow`, which lays under Accompanist Pager.

---

If you're using Compose 1.1.0 or earlier, you can use the following solution:

Since version **0.19.0** the Accompaniment Pager has been [re-written](https://github.com/google/accompanist/blob/0f2dfd236108e80f593d949bf1a8e6b394459e54/docs/pager.md#changes-in-v0190) to be based on `LazyRow` and `LazyColumn`.

Lazy views do not support disabling scrolling for now, you can star [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/201150093) to bring more attention to this problem and follow updates.

Here's a workaround for now:

```
private val VerticalScrollConsumer = object : NestedScrollConnection {
    override fun onPreScroll(available: Offset, source: NestedScrollSource) = available.copy(x = 0f)
    override suspend fun onPreFling(available: Velocity) = available.copy(x = 0f)
}

private val HorizontalScrollConsumer = object : NestedScrollConnection {
    override fun onPreScroll(available: Offset, source: NestedScrollSource) = available.copy(y = 0f)
    override suspend fun onPreFling(available: Velocity) = available.copy(y = 0f)
}

fun Modifier.disabledVerticalPointerInputScroll(disabled: Boolean = true) =
    if (disabled) this.nestedScroll(VerticalScrollConsumer) else this

fun Modifier.disabledHorizontalPointerInputScroll(disabled: Boolean = true) =
    if (disabled) this.nestedScroll(HorizontalScrollConsumer) else this
```

Usage:

```
HorizontalPager(
    count = 10,
    modifier = Modifier.disabledHorizontalPointerInputScroll()
) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thx man, I'll try on this.

Comment: Hey, this seems to be working. I had the exact same need and tried to use `pointerInput` to consume horizontal drags, but that didn't work.

Comment: @Daivid I've updated my answer, if you're using Compose **1.2.0-alpha**, you can use new API.

Comment: @PhilipDukhov Oh, good to know, I'm still on 1.1.0-rc01. I'll check it out.

Answer (score 1):

As of jetpack compose version **1.4.0-alpha03** `HorizontalPager` and `VerticalPager` are part of foundation as `androidx.compose.foundation.pager.HorizontalPager`.

Same flag `userScrollEnabled = false` does what accompaniest version does. You need to change `count` to `pageCount` in default version however.

```
fun HorizontalPager(
    pageCount: Int,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    state: PagerState = rememberPagerState(),
    contentPadding: PaddingValues = PaddingValues(0.dp),
    pageSize: PageSize = PageSize.Fill,
    beyondBoundsPageCount: Int = 0,
    pageSpacing: Dp = 0.dp,
    verticalAlignment: Alignment.Vertical = Alignment.CenterVertically,
    flingBehavior: SnapFlingBehavior = PagerDefaults.flingBehavior(state = state),
    userScrollEnabled: Boolean = true,
    reverseLayout: Boolean = false,
    key: ((index: Int) -> Any)? = null,
    pageNestedScrollConnection: NestedScrollConnection = PagerDefaults.pageNestedScrollConnection(
        Orientation.Horizontal
    ),
    pageContent: @Composable (page: Int) -> Unit
)
```

Answer (score 0):

A workaround you can use is declare a `Box` in front of your pager in order to intercept the drag gesture.
Something like below:

```kotlin
var dragEnable by remember {
    mutableStateOf(true)
}

Box {
    HorizontalPager(...) { page ->
        // Content of your pager... 
    }
    if (!dragEnable) {
        // This box will intercept the drag gesture and do nothing.
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .pointerInput(Unit) {
                    detectDragGestures(
                        onDrag = { change, offset ->
                            change.consumeAllChanges()
                        }
                    )
                },
        )
    }
}
```